# What happens if a double-faced card that is copying a different double-faced card that is part of a melded creature tries to meld?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-double-faced-cards

We already have a [similar question about double faced cards transforming](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/42692/what-happens-if-a-double-faced-card-that-is-copying-a-different-double-faced-car), however, this covers a single card transforming. Meld exiles a pair of cards and returns them "transformed" into a single card.

Say a player controls [Hanweir Battlements](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHanweir%20Battlements%5d) and also controls a [Chandra, Fire of Kaladesh](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bChandra%2c%20Fire%20of%20Kaladesh%5d) enchanted with [Metamorphic Alteration](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMetamorphic%20Alteration%5d) to be a copy of [Hanweir Garrison](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHanweir%20Garrison%5d). What happens when the meld effect tries to create [Hanweir, the Writhing Township](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHanweir%2c%20the%20Writhing%20Township%5d) but can't?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hanweir Battlements and Chandra are exiled permanently. The Metamorphic Alteration goes to the graveyard.**

As you already noted, only meld cards can meld. You can exile Chandra and the Battlements with Battlement's ability, but those two cards cannot return melded.

> 701.36b Only two cards belonging to the same meld pair can be melded. Tokens, cards that aren’t meld cards, or meld cards that don’t form a meld pair can’t be melded.
>
> 701.36c If an effect instructs a player to meld cards that can’t be melded, they stay in their current zone.

Note that 701.36b calls for meld *cards*, not meld *objects*. Being able to meld is a property of the card, not of the object represented by it.